# ImportError: No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python-3.x, module, kivy

I have 3 Projects:

1. The weather app from the Book "Creating Apps in Kivy" that i have completed.
2. A StudentDB app from a Youtube Tutorial.
3. The beginning of my own app.

The first two still work. But if i want to build my own, `kivy` is not known.

I have thrown everything out but the basics. I do not know why `kivy` only runs for project my first projects. I had no issue with the other ones. But i cannot escape the issue.

I have tried `pip install kivy` but it is already installed, i do not know the version though.

I use `Python 3.5.6` in the `Anaconda` bundle.

I have tried making a new Project and abandoning my old.

## Begin of code i used

```
from kivy.app import App

class BasicApp(App):
    pass
```

## End of code i used

Does anyone know this issue? Do i have to install something special? I am not sure how to handle this one.

Comment: Please, clarify shortly your problem, the code you run, the result you expect, and the error you get. Shortly.

Comment: My Problem is, that I cannot use kivy anymore, because i get the message ImportError: No module Kivy found. I run the really basic code in the description. But i don see an issue with the code, but rather with kivy. I am confused that it worked on my first two projects and now it is not.

Comment: What is the output of `import kivy`?

Comment: I just have the Import Error. There is not really an output.

Comment: I would uninstall and reinstall the package. Wait for other suggestions, though.

Comment: You tip was good, i had to reapply the Kivy Package to the PyCharm Project interpreter. Thanks for the inspiration. Now everything is fine.